# How to avoid cursor use in dynamic sql update?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, dynamic-sql

So, I'm trying to rewrite some of the stored procedures we're using to use better set-based logic and reduce or eliminate the use of cursors due to performance issues.  However, I can't come up with a more efficient way to do the below without resorting to cursor use.

Presently, what i'm doing is basically selecting an initial result set into a temporary table that looks something like

```
INSERT INTO #tmptable
SELECT stuff.id
    ,stuff.datapoint
    ,stuff.database
    ,'' AS missingdata
FROM STUFF
```

Which usually returns anywhere from 250-500 rows of information.  The '' is a datapoint that lives in any one of several hundred other databases - the name of which is specified by stuff.database.  Despite there being hundreds of possible options, there's usually only three or four *unique* databases in each result set.  As a result, what I'm currently doing is:

```
DECLARE @dbname VARCHAR(255)
DECLARE a_cursor CURSOR LOCAL
FOR
SELECT DISTINCT database
FROM #tmptable

OPEN a_cursor

FETCH NEXT
FROM a_cursor
INTO @dbname

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    SET @SQL = 'UPDATE #tmptable
                SET missingdata = bin.dataaggregate
                FROM ((SELECT pd.id id
                ,STUFF((SELECT '','' + pdd.bin
                     FROM server.[' + @dbname + '].dbo.proddetails pdd
                     WHERE pdd.id= pd.id 
                     GROUP BY pdd.id, pdd.bin
                     FOR XML PATH(''''), TYPE).value(''.'', ''VARCHAR(max)''), 1, 1, '''') dataaggregate
                FROM server.[' + @dbname + '].dbo.proddetails pd) bin
                INNER JOIN #tmptable tir ON tir.id= bin.id
EXEC sp_executesql @SQL

FETCH NEXT
FROM a_cursor
INTO @dbname
END

CLOSE a_cursor

DEALLOCATE a_cursor
```

Since there are usually only a handful of databases needed in each result set, the cursor has to loop only a handful of times and the performance hit isn't awful.  Still, I don't like using them and feel like there has to be a more efficient way to do this.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
INSERT INTO #tmptable
SELECT stuff.id
    ,stuff.datapoint
    ,stuff.[database]
    ,'' AS missingdata
    ,row_number() over (order by stuff.id) as rn
FROM STUFF

declare @i int= 1;
declare @max int = (select max(rn) from #tmptable)
while @i <= @max
begin
    declare @dbname sysname
    select @dbname = [database] from #tmptable where rn = @i

    --exec your dynamic sql hear
    set @i +=1
end
```

Comment: Wouldn't this cause the dynamic sql to be executed 300 times (that is, once for every row) rather than the three or four executions of the cursor variant?

Comment: [So you think you have eliminated a cursor, do you?](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2012/01/26/the-fallacy-that-a-while-loop-isn-t-a-cursor.aspx)

Comment: cursor and while loop it is not the same think! So you ask "how to avoid cursor use", my post is answered on your question.

Comment: Row by row is row by row, doesn't matter if it's an explicit cursor or an implicit one. [Did you read the link?](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2012/01/26/the-fallacy-that-a-while-loop-isn-t-a-cursor.aspx)